# seeing if something exists in laravel auth/user object

Tags: php, html, laravel

QUite simply, if I do this in my blade:

```
<h3>{{Auth::user()->modules}}</h3>
```

As a test dump, I get an array of user modules like [{id:1, name:"module one"}] but the list has about 20 modules there.

What I want to do is hide certain nav items if the module "read-only" exists for the user.

How can I properly say 'if module name "read-only" exists ... else ... like this

```
@if({{Auth::user()->modules `name contains read only` //don't know the syntax to use here}}

<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>

@else

<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>

@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use collection search.

```
 @if( Auth::user()->modules->search('read_only') )
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-search

Comment: `search` returns the key and wouldn't look into the properties of the objects, `contains` can though

Comment: @lagbox so can I just replace search with contains?

Comment: well you will be replacing one method call for the other but you have to look at the documentation to see how to use it for what you need